# SQL query help to calculate max

Tags: sql, data-modeling, google-bigquery

I have a question regarding a query I need to do in SQL (i use BQ).

I have this table:

```
train_no, wagon_no, weight, length, date, startpoint(km), endpoint(km)
1, 123, 1000, 20, 20190101, 0, 7
1, 234, 2000, 20, 20190101, 1, 2
1, 345, 3000, 30, 20190101, 1, 5
1, 456, 1000, 40, 20190101, 1, 6
2, 987, 1000, 10, 20190101, 0, 8
2, 876, 2000, 20, 20190101, 1, 2
2, 765, 3000, 20, 20190101, 1, 5
2, 654, 1000, 20, 20190101, 1, 6
```

The table shows two trains with wagons. Per wagon we see at what point the wagon was added on the train. So for train no 1 we see that wagon 234 was included on the train from startpoint=1 (kilometer 1) to endpoint=2 (kilometer 2) then it was removed from the train. We also see that max endpoint is 7 for train_no =1 so max travelled distance for the train is 7 km.

The total train length and weight varies during the distance and I would like to calculate the maximum length and maximum weight reached during the distance. How can I do this in SQL?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Edit:
Adding a pic to clearify what Im looking for. 
As you can see in attached pic Train_no =1 have a max weight between point 1 and 2. Total weight is 7000 and is the total of all wagons in the train at that specific distance. Also, total length is 110 which is the total length of the all wagons added together.
[image]

Comment: select a.train_no, a.wagon_no, max(a.weight) as max_wt, max(length) as max_len from  
( select train_no, wagon_no, weight, length, endpoint(km) - startpoint(km) as distance from MyTable ) a 
group by a.train_no, a.wagon_no, a.distance;

Comment: Thanks for your help @ManojKumar but this wouldnt give me the max length or weight during the distance? I mean if a wagon have start point = 0 and end point 1 (distance =1) will get grouped with at wagon with start point = 1 and end point = 2 (distance =1) so the wagons havent been in the same distance. There is a combination of all distances when the train have a max weight and length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT train_no, dt, MIN(startpoint) startpoint, MAX(endpoint) endpoint
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  GROUP BY train_no, dt
)
SELECT train_no, dt, MAX(wagons) max_wagons, MAX(total_weight) AS max_total_weight, MAX(total_len) max_total_len
FROM (
  SELECT train_no, dt, point, COUNT(wagon_no) wagons, SUM(weight) total_weight, SUM(len) total_len 
  FROM temp, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(startpoint, endpoint)) point
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
  USING(train_no, dt)
  WHERE point >= t.startpoint AND point < t.endpoint
  GROUP BY train_no, dt, point
)
GROUP BY train_no, dt
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 train_no, 123 wagon_no, 1000 weight, 20 len, '20190101' dt, 0 startpoint, 7 endpoint UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 234, 2000, 20, '20190101', 1, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 345, 3000, 30, '20190101', 1, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 456, 1000, 40, '20190101', 1, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 987, 1000, 10, '20190101', 0, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 876, 2000, 20, '20190101', 1, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 765, 3000, 20, '20190101', 1, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 654, 1000, 20, '20190101', 1, 6 
), temp AS (
  SELECT train_no, dt, MIN(startpoint) startpoint, MAX(endpoint) endpoint
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  GROUP BY train_no, dt
)
SELECT train_no, dt, MAX(wagons) max_wagons, MAX(total_weight) AS max_total_weight, MAX(total_len) max_total_len
FROM (
  SELECT train_no, dt, point, COUNT(wagon_no) wagons, SUM(weight) total_weight, SUM(len) total_len 
  FROM temp, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(startpoint, endpoint)) point
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
  USING(train_no, dt)
  WHERE point >= t.startpoint AND point < t.endpoint
  GROUP BY train_no, dt, point
)
GROUP BY train_no, dt
```

result is

```
Row train_no    dt          max_wagons  max_total_weight    max_total_len    
1   1           20190101    4           7000                110  
2   2           20190101    4           7000                70
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: glad it works for you. please also consider voting up the answer

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns the the length at each KM marker sorted in descending fashion for each train.

```
with data as (
  select 1 as train_no, 123 as wagon_no, 1000 as weight, 20 as length, 20190101 as date, 0 as startpoint, 7 as endpoint union all
  select 1, 234, 2000, 20, 20190101, 1, 2 union all
  select 1, 345, 3000, 30, 20190101, 1, 5 union all
  select 1, 456, 1000, 40, 20190101, 1, 6 union all
  select 2, 987, 1000, 10, 20190101, 0, 8 union all
  select 2, 876, 2000, 20, 20190101, 1, 2 union all
  select 2, 765, 3000, 20, 20190101, 1, 5 union all
  select 2, 654, 1000, 20, 20190101, 1, 6
),
km_array as (
  select * from unnest(generate_array(0,10)) km
),
joined as (
  select *
  from km_array
  cross join data
  where km between startpoint and endpoint
),
train_length_at_each_km as (
  select
    km,
    train_no,
    sum(length) as length
  from joined
  group by 1,2
)
select
  train_no, length, km
from train_length_at_each_km 
order by train_no, length desc
```

Getting maximum weight would use similar logic as the `train_length_at_each_km` CTE.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this one too!